# Wordpress Thesis Theme Custom Function

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

I am curious to know what the '1' in the following code means?

```
add_action('thesis_hook_footer','my_widgetized_footer','1');
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tells how important your function is. Alter this to make your function be called before or after other functions. The default is 10, so (for example) setting it to 5 would make it run earlier and setting it to 12 would make it run later.